# C# Linq - Issue with joining tables with multiple fields - Error CS1941

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq which I believe is syntactically correct.

```
 var result = from t1 in context.t1
              join t2 in context.t2
              on new { t1.field1, t1.field2 } equals new { t2.field1, t2.field2 }
              select new { t1, t2 };
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
CS1941 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

On checking the database, I found the following:

```
table1                  |   table2
                        |
field1      varchar(16) |   field1  varchar(50)
field2      varchar(30) |   field2  varchar(50)
```

Should the fields data type and length match?

Comment: Check the types in your code: `t1.field1` must be the same type as `t2.field1`, and the same for `t2`. The linked duplicate explains in more detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
       Can you please try this .


       var result = from x in entity
         join y in entity2
         on new { X1= x.field1, X2= x.field2 } equals new { X1=y.field1, X2= y.field2 }
         select new 
         {
           /// Columns
          };
```